# Google IME or Redhat Japanese IME candidate window not positioned correctly for Swing textfield

Tags: java, swing, ime

Is there any input method interface I need to implement to make ime candidate window display at cursor position? Windows default ime seems to display at the correct position, but not google ime and RedHat ime. Here's some sample code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

class ime
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("TextField Example");
        JTextField t1, t2;
        t1 = new JTextField("Welcome to Javatpoint.");
        t1.setBounds(50, 100, 200, 30);
        t2 = new JTextField("AWT Tutorial");
        t2.setBounds(50, 150, 200, 30);
        f.add(t1);
        f.add(t2);
        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: google ime not positioned correctly]

**Answer:** This is a known [Swing bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8089271). The only workaround I can think of is create a new window with a textfield that overlay on top (not a full solution, still have to deal with window moving/resize, etc):

```
public class FakeTextField implements FocusListener
{

    JFrame frame;
    JTextField textfield;

    JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
    JTextField textfield2;

    public FakeTextField(JFrame frame, JTextField textfield, JTextField textfield2)
    {
        this.frame = frame;
        frame2.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        this.textfield = textfield;
        this.textfield2 = textfield2;
        textfield.addFocusListener(this);
        textfield2.addFocusListener(new FocusListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)
            {
                frame2.setVisible(false);
            }

        });

        frame2.add(textfield2);
    }

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)
    {
        try
        {
            textfield2.setText(textfield.getText());
            frame2.setUndecorated(true);
        }
        catch(Exception err)
        {

        }
        frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame2.setSize(textfield.getSize());
        frame2.setLocation(textfield.getLocationOnScreen());
        frame2.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)
    {
    }

}
```

Comment: more information: this problem does not happen if you use awt.Textfield instead of swing.JTextField

Answer (score 0):

The below is really a comment and not an answer, but I can't format a comment as well as I can an answer.

This is how I do it in my *Swing* GUI for Hebrew (which is written from right to left)

```java
java.awt.im.InputContext ic = t1.getInputContext(); // 't1' is the JTextField from the code you posted.
ic.selectInputMethod(new java.util.Locale("iw", "IL");
```

*iw* is the language code for Hebrew.
*IL* is the country code for Israel

Comment: sorry, the question is not how to select input method but how to display the candidate window at correct position (below cursor).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but rather hinting you on how to proceed:
The class SwingUtilities has several methods to convert component coordinates to screen coordinates.

You need to get the component position on the screen and display the small window at that position with a small offset at your liking.

Comment: The issue is Google IME is outside of Java Swing control. The only communication between them is through the Input Method Framework (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/imf/spec.html). However, windows default ime can pick up the correct position, but google ime cannot. So the problem is: how to make google ime receive that information?